# Use markers in After Effects as triggers for a particular animation

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

I have a one precomp animations (from stocks). And I am searching for a script /expression that will automate a certain animation for my project. 
I have a long videos with premade subtitles srt file and I want to use subtitles timestamps  (not a subtitle text content!) convert them to markers an link that one animation precomp to each and every starting marker on a specific AE layer. Finally I wanto to trigger an animation precomp by starting markers of on a layer.

Suppose I have 3 hour video with 30 captions in a one .srt file. 
I import a video then I import .srt file via pt_importsubtitles (it will convert stamps to markers) and I will have a video already in sync with 30 imported markers on a АЕ layer from a one .srt file.

Importantly, I do not interested of any imported text captions (although it will be good if text will be imported to marker's comment field) but only thing I am interested is (markers) timstamps of a srt file.

I want to buy a script that will link a precomp to bunch of (timestamps) markers.

Only thing i found is this video

Any help for a complete dummy in AE?

Comment: What was wrong with what the video described?

Comment: A tool is found Duik > animation blender (suggested by  Аркадий Чумаков) but I I can not get it work with animated icons from videohive.

Answer (score 1):

Markers are a special time of key, basically you can think of them as keys on a property of the layer called "marker", just like you can use keys on say, the position property. To access a marker on a layer you use

```js
var myMarker = marker.key(n)
```

where *n* is the number of the key you want (counting from 1, not zero. WTF Adobe?) or alternatively:

```js
var myMarker = marker.nearestKey(time)
```

Which will give you the nearest key, which can be ahead of or behind the current time.

Once you have the markerKey object you can get its time, duration, index (useful if you used the nearestKey method), and all of the metadata that can be stored in markers (quite a lot). Details about all the marker properties [here](http://expressions.aenhancers.com/markerkey.html). For example, if your marker has a comment, you can get the text of the comment thus

```js
var myMarker = marker.key(n);
var theComment = myMarker.comment;
```

You can access comp markers too, just use

```js
var myMarker = thisComp.marker.key(n); //or
var myOtherMarker = thisCom.marker.nearestKey(time);
```

Comment: Hello
Expressions is little bit advanced for me. Sorry 
Аркадий Чумаков suggested me "animation blender" in Duik 16
It works (trigger an animation by marker) but it works for now inside one comp and shape layer within it.
When I pick an animation from VideoHive (icon) nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Marker Remap at www.aescripts.com/marker-remap . It takes the principles from the video you reference above and adds a powerful After Effects panel to control marker additions and timing.

Comment: It can be used for my purposes ? Trigger an imported animation (precomp) from stocks (titles or icons animations) by starting markers (foremerly (starting) time stamps in Subtitle Edit) on a layer ?

Answer (score 0):

In a small touch of self-advertising, I'd like to refer to the free script [MarkerTriggery](http://markertriggery.com/) for AE. It brings a neat UI you can control your markers from, and you don't need to know anything about expressions to use it.

Comment: What about importing timestamps from subtitle .srt file and convert starting stamps to MarkerTrigger ? 
I have one icon animation precomp and I have to link it to multiple markers on a timeline layer.
It is possible to do it without manual work and minimum expressions writing ?

Comment: Hey Cloddo, that’s a great idea that I totally never thought about. I’ll look into that. It’s definitely not supported in the script, but I might look into it in the future and get back to you here.

Comment: I hope my Stackexchange question will be finally solved after a year. I used to use pt_importsubtitles for converting srt timstams to markers and intrestingly text content of subtitles will go into marker comment field (Hope you will have that feature). But then I was unaible to link a one precomp animation to all (starting) markers on a layer. I hope your plugin will handle that soon even if MarkerTrigger will be payed. Ready to support it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey Simon Heimbuchner, any news ?